# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DEPARTM' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the few columns in that I'm trying to add two columns to together from two different tables.The Error is as below

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DEPARTM' to data type int.
```

when i checked both the columns from two tables the filed for DEPARTM  was same in both the columns from two tables , like the result should be as departm - departm .
since the first table cdm has columns listed as numbers and names and the cc table consists of all descriptions but, when it comes to respite it is listed as name in both the columns . so I'm hoping it's not converting.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is overloaded to mean both addition and string concatenation.  The simplest solution is to use the `CONCAT()` function:

```
CONCAT(cdm.Subcategory, ' - ',  cc.SubcategoryDescription) as CodeDesc
```

If you want leading zeros, then use `FORMAT()`:

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(cdm.Subcategory, '0000'), ' - ',  cc.SubcategoryDescription) as CodeDesc
```

Comment: It's not working sir.

Comment: @kreme123 . . . What does "not working" mean?

Comment: it still shows the same error sir.

Comment: @kreme123 . . . Then the code that you have shown is not where the error is.

Comment: what's your email? illl send you code its lengthy